# Unable to import google PlusShare class from com.google.android.gms.plus?

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

I am unable to import Google PlusShare class from package com.google.android.gms.plus?

I don't know why it's happening. I already added google play service libray into my project.

`import com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusShare;`

But still its not importing my file and giving me syntax error.

**The import com.google.android.gms.plus cannot be resolved**

Previously it was working fine until I updated my Google play services library using android SDK manager. My previous verion was 42**** something. But since I updated to this verion of google play library It won't work anymore. Now, I am using "**4452000**" version of google play services.

Any help would be really appreciated

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try remove and re-adding google play services from you workspace

Comment: I tried this....but it won't work again...

Comment: Are you using Android Studio or Eclipse? Are you using the apk or the sources? Are you seeing any errors about references in R.java / R.class?

Answer (score 2):

Hey I was facing the same problem and I just found a solution for this don't use

> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'

just use this

> **implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'**

Hope this is helpful to you 
Good day
**Happy Coding**

Answer (score 0):

I've had same problem with Google PlusShare import.
Adding `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.3.0'` to application level build.gradle solved this problem.